# Field from default language should be valid for all languages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, templavoila, flexform

I'm using this bit of Typoscript and a Templavoilà Plus input field to generate some text.

```
10 = TEXT
10.value.field = field_test
```

I work with English (default) and German contents. When I translate a content to German, the backend user has to fill in again `field_test`, which is the normal behaviour.

**Modifying the Typoscript**, how can I only use the English (default) content of the `field_test` even in the German content?

Put in other words, **how can I get the value of a field of a particular language**?

I saw `LLL:` and `l10n_mode`, can they be of any help? And if so, how can you use them in that case?

*Is it even possible to achieve that with a simple Header of a tt_content?*

Or could I use something like that to disable localisation of a single Templavoilà field ?

```
config.sys_language_softExclude = tt_content:subheader
config.sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank = tt_content:subheader
```

---

*The reason why I'm asking this, is because it would be quite useful not to have to fill in again TV fields for links or images for example…*

---

Here is my Typoscript, where `field_test` is created with Templavoilà and filled in by an backend editor:

```
  5 = IMAGE
  5 {
    if.isTrue.field = field_test
    file = fileadmin/icons/test.png
    wrap = <li>|</li>  

    imageLinkWrap = 1
    imageLinkWrap.enable = 1
    imageLinkWrap.typolink.parameter.field = field_test
    }
```

---

I have tried modifying the **Data Structure XML** as follow, but even though I have no content in the German `field_test`, it doesn't display the Default/English content.

```
<meta type="array">
 <langDisable>1</langDisable>
 <langChildren>1</langChildren>
</meta>
…
<field_test type="array">
 <tx_templavoilaplus type="array">
 <title>Test</title>
 <langOverlayMode>ifBlank</langOverlayMode>
 …
</field_test>
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete guess, maybe insertData = 1 helps out??

```
  5 = IMAGE
  5 {
    if.isTrue.field = field_test
    file = fileadmin/icons/test.png
    wrap = <li>|</li>  

    imageLinkWrap = 1
    imageLinkWrap.enable = 1
    imageLinkWrap.insertData = 1
    imageLinkWrap.typolink.parameter.field = field_test
    }
```